# CreateProcessW with target passed via stdin - cannot find the target

Tags: c, windows, widechar

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
int main(int argc, wchar_t** argv)
{
    DWORD bytes_read;
    WCHAR* buffer[4096];
    LPWSTR str;
    STARTUPINFO  start_info = { 0 };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info = { 0 };

    ReadFile(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), buffer, 4096, &bytes_read, NULL);
    str = malloc(bytes_read);
    memcpy(str, buffer, bytes_read);

    // debug - stdout + file
    wprintf(L"\nTrying to run -> \"%LS\"", str);
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    fwprintf(f, L"%LS", str);
    fclose(f);

    BOOL result = CreateProcessW(
        NULL,
        str,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        TRUE,
        CREATE_NO_WINDOW | NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &start_info,
        &process_info
    );

    if (!result) {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        WCHAR *errstr;

        FormatMessage(
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL, err,
            MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            (LPWSTR)&errstr, 0, NULL
        );

        wprintf(L"\nError -> %ls", errstr);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Running it yields following

```
C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\Debug                         
λ php -r "echo \"C:\\Windows\\System32\\PING.EXE\0\";"|ConsoleApplication1.exe

Trying to run -> "C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE"                               
Error -> The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So it seems it uses correct input. Also in file.txt there doesn't seem to be anything suspicious when viewed in hex editor

[image: hex dump of a file]

When hardcoding str like following instead of using stdin

```
wchar_t cmd[] = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\PING.EXE";
```

It works.

What do I need to do in order to make CreateProcessW work with stdin input?

Comment: Does that look like a wide-character UTF-16 string to you? Whatever encoding this `echo` command uses (hopefully UTF-8 since the filesystem is Unicode), you'll need to decode the string using that encoding, e.g. via `MultiByteToWideChar` or by any other means you're comfortable with.

Comment: I did try to pipe utf-16 as well, didn't have any effect on this. Instead of condescending tone, modify the example and verify if it works for you

Comment: I'm sorry you read that as a condescending tone; I assure you it was not meant that way. It was meant to draw your attention to something that should eventually become second-nature to how you approach a problem like this. Think about what the function expects, and examine the inputs carefully. Look at the memory dump of the string. That's a single-byte string. We cannot pass it to `CreateProcessW`; it will just be gobbledygook. I would default to decoding the input as ANSI and at least have an option to force decoding as UTF-8 since filesystem paths are Unicode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> WCHAR* buffer[4096];
> ```

This will create an array of character strings. You just want one wide char buffer.

Use the `L"%s"` format specifier for testing:

```
wprintf(L"%s\n", buffer)
```

If possible, pass the Unicode text as command line, example

```
php -r "echo \"Test...\0\";"|app.exe Unicode
```

The Unicode text can contain UTF16 character sets.

```
int main(void)
{
    wprintf(L"GetCommandLineW %s\n", GetCommandLineW());

    DWORD bytes_read = 0;
    char buffer[4096] = { 0 };
    ReadFile(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), buffer,
        sizeof(buffer), &bytes_read, NULL);

    int codepage = CP_UTF8;//or CP_ACP
    int wlen = MultiByteToWideChar(codepage, 0, buffer, -1, 0, 0);
    wchar_t *wstr = malloc(wlen * 2);
    MultiByteToWideChar(codepage, 0, buffer, -1, wstr, wlen);

    wprintf(L"pipe %s\n", wstr);

    free(wstr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP is piping from `php.exe -r "echo ...`. I don't know how it gets its command line (as ANSI or UTF-16) or whether it transcodes to another encoding (ANSI, OEM, UTF-8) when writing to a pipe. Ideally it gets the command line via `GetCommandLineW` (UTF-16) and writes UTF-8 to the pipe, but it probably writes ANSI to the pipe, which is hideously bad and the OP should try to fix that if it's the case. I highly doubt PHP uses the console input codepage (`GetConsoleCP`) for any of this, and I'm sorry to say that suggesting `ReadConsole` makes no sense. stdin is a pipe, not a console.

Comment: @eryksun, I missed the php part. I guess I can't salvage this answer. `php -r "echo \"Test...\0\";"|app.exe Unicode` should make `"Unicode"` available in `GetCommandLineW` with UTF16 encoding, I don't know if that's an option. `"Test"` may not show up in command line.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if utf8 is being piped or ansi, since example uses lower bytes only, which are same in both character sets

Comment: @gadelat, obviously not if the Universe were ASCII only, but it matters in general because filesystem paths are Unicode. For example, mojibake problems commonly occur with profile directories in "C:\Users" when legacy non-Unicode programs have baked in assumptions about ASCII, ANSI, and OEM byte strings.

Comment: I know and that's the entire point why I'm trying to make this program unicode, BUT it shouldn't matter in THIS example. ANSI/UTF8 differences don't make any difference in this example, hence it's not a root of the problem why it doesn't work.

Comment: Your program is not working. And it's because you have an ANSI buffer and you use it in a wide function. It does make a difference in this example.

Comment: I'm talking about input. My code wouldn't work regardless if input is utf8 or ansi :)

Comment: Note that `wprintf(L"%S\n", "Text")` looks like is printing Unicode, but it is actually printing ANSI. That's why your program was printing the right output, yet `CreateProcessW` failed because it was getting the ANSI input. My suggestion will work if you have ANSI input, it will convert it for `CreateProcessW`. Unfortunately I don't know how to pass Unicode with php pipe (except as command line parameter)

Comment: I was unable to use Unicode with this command: `php -r "echo 'ελληνικά';"` It just prints `"e???????"` no matter what I do. Using `GetCommandLineW` might be an easier option.